# Datatype which can store very large value in C

Tags: c, type-conversion, unsigned-long-long-int

Recently in programming contest in [Here](http://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/geeko-and-tree-2/?utm_campaign=user-activity-email&utm_medium=email&utm_source=problem-solved), the problem is pretty straight forward but catch is with worst case scenario which we have to handle data of size  `10^10000` .

I tried the program in `python` which is straight forward as i don't have to specify the datatype(It is taken care by the compiler ) but when i tried with `C` I couldn't find the correct datatype . 
(I tried uintmax_t which didn't work out too).

So how to approach very huge type of data's in C ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in datatype in `C` that can store that big values. You will either have to write your own implementation or use a library. As this is a competition, though the second is not an option. Every now and then similar problems appear and usually the best approach is to use another language e.g. java(as it is usually available on competitions).